# How can I let one element do two events at the same time

Tags: javascript

so, I'm having a game, and I want the user to reset the score when he clicks the button, and reset boundaries when he hovers over it.
How can I do it so that he can both, hover and click

```
function reset_bounderies() {


    let start = document.getElementById("start")
    start.addEventListener("mouseover", function (event) {
        game = true;
        document.querySelectorAll(".boundary:not(.example)").forEach(item => {
            item.classList.remove("youlose")
            document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = `Begin by moving your mouse over the "S".`
        })
    })
    start();

}
```

and the second function

```
function reset_game() {

    let start = document.getElementById("start")
    start.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
        game = true;
        score = 0;
        print_score()
        
    })
    start();
}
```

P.S: I can't edit html or css file

Comment: Why do you add event listeners inside the function? Why do you call HTML elements? What do you expect to happen? That looks wrong. Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: You don't need to put the event listeners inside the functions. Take them out of the `reset_bounderies()` [sic] and `reset_game()` functions and try again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add two differents `EventListener` to your button

```js
function functionOne(){
  console.log("functionOne")
}

function functionTwo(){
  console.log("functionTwo")
}

const myButton = document.getElementById("myButton")

myButton.addEventListener('click', functionOne)
myButton.addEventListener('mouseover', functionTwo)
```

```html
<button id="myButton">Click me !</button>
```

Comment: Yeah, sorry, forgot to mention that I can't edit the html or css files

Comment: Sorry, I added the js version and removed the html version. thank you for your comment i didn't know it was a bad pratice